# Using Apache Haus for Reverse Proxy in Windows 10

Tags: apache, windows-10, httpd.conf

I install Apache Haus in my Windows 10 PC, that should work as Reverse Proxy.

my setting in **httpd-vhosts.conf** is like below:

```
<VirtualHost _default_:80>
    DocumentRoot "$(SRVROOT)/htdocs"
    ProxyRequests off
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyPass / http://172.17.3.177/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://172.17.3.177/
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost _default_:80>
    DocumentRoot "${SRVROOT}/htdocs"
    ProxyRequests off
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyPass / http://172.17.3.177/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://172.17.3.177/

    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile "${SRVROOT}/conf/ssl/server.crt"
    SSLCertificateKeyFile "${SRVROOT}/conf/ssl/server.key"
</VirtualHost>
```

When I open **http://localhost** in browser the website from **172.17.3.177**, successfully rendered (see below pic)

[image]

But when I try https://localhost my browser shows failure.

[image]

Can anybody help? I already disable windows firewall.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have never implemented HTTPS on Apache.
However, your configuration seems to miss the listening to port 443 which is the default port for HTTPS.
You should add

```
Listen 443 // instruction at global server configuration
<VirtualHost _default_:443> // in your VirtualHost definition
```